# Why setInterval(,0) makes animation much smoother in NativeScript?

Tags: android, performance, nativescript, setinterval, angular-nativescript

I'm working on custom animation (screen blinking with 60fps) on Android, and I was very surprised that using of stupid `setInterval(() => {...}, 0)` works much better that the native android's Choreographer.

With `setInterval(() => {...}, 0)` I've got stable 60 FPS even on android 5 devices, but with Choreographer (that should work much efficiency, code below) I got drops to 50 FPS on powerful OnePlus 6 on Android 9.0

`android.view.Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(...);`

But if I write down `setInterval(() => null);` near the Choreographer callback definition - I will achieve stable FPS and low GPU utilisation (LOL, right?).

So I have created app on playground where everybody can test it. Turn on 'Profile GPU rendering' - 'On screen as bars' in 'developer options' menu and launch this simple app with simple loader on 2 pages - one with absolutely empty component, another one with `setInterval(() => {}, 0)`

https://play.nativescript.org/?id=yRTcJk&v=1

As result - empty component renders loader at 58-60 FPS with full GPU utilization (up to 60FPS line), **but** in component with empty setInterval - stable 60 FPS and 1/3 way to 60FPS utilization.

Can anybody say what is going on?

UPD: added GIF's (second one - with `setInterval(() => null);` )

[image: Loader with empty component]
[image: Loader with empty setInterval(,0) in component]

Comment: See [SO Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful). Read it **ALL**, *some answers* are *wrong* !

Comment: @JonGoodwin sorry, but how is it applicable here? I talk about NativeScript and that fact, that any animation runs much better with ```setInterval(() => null)``` in controller.

Comment: 'NativeScript' uses the underlying JavaScript functions, it's all there in the link. Have you read it ?

Comment: @JonGoodwin yes, I read it. And I understand how this works in JS. But first of all I think that NS overrides setInterval/setTimeout function to pass them directly to native layer. And I don’t realise how can **empty** setInterval function speedup app's frame drawing time.